# My Water bamboo inside house healthy or not? Do I have to move it outside?

Tags: plant-care

This is my water bamboo I got it last week

Do I need to put it outside?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wonder if your bamboo is simply older and has more established wood?

Comment: I put another pic, I am not sure if my plant is old age or not

Comment: You want to know if a tropical plant belongs in the sun?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bad idea to grow bamboo indoors. I have a small bamboo houseplant myself, although a different kind. In my opinion, what is most important is meeting the plants requirements. If you can provide it with everything it needs then you can keep it indoors. Just keep an eye on it in the beginning months to see how it adjusts.